# How to prove that (P v (P ^ Q)) iff P?

Tags: logic, proof, symbolic-logic

How to prove (P v (P ^ Q)) ≡ P? I am not sure how to get rid of proposition Q. I am allowed to use Leibniz and apply Substitution. I already came across most calculation rules in the book: *Logical Reasoning A First Course*.

I am looking for a hint. Not necessarily the answer!

Edit: I'm sorry, I forgot that it needed to be solved using calculations. And I don't have access to weakening rules.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to prove it *by cases* (∨–Elim). The general form is:

> If you have: ⊢ (A ∨ B),  A ⊢ C, and B ⊢ C
>
> Then you can conclude: (A ∨ B) ⊢ C

This means that if you've proved (A ∨ B) and you have proved (i) C from assumption A, and (ii) C from assumption B, then you have proved C from assumption (A ∨ B). This rule will give you the → direction.

To get the other direction, that is, from P to P ∨ (P ∧ Q), there is a rule (∨–Intro) to the effect that:

> If you have: ⊢ A
>
> Then you can conclude: ⊢ A ∨ B                                                                          (for *any* sentence B)

Needless to say, if your system doesn't have those rules, then if it's *complete* (in the technical sense), then there *must* be some other set of rules or axioms that will allow you to prove the equivalence; your task in that case is to find those rules and apply them or find those axioms and instantiate them with the appropriate sentence letters.

Answer (score 3):

This will greatly depend on the rules you have access to.

I would suggest the following strategy derive two implications by making two arguments by assumption: 
Side 1:

```
(1) | P  as assumption 
(2) | P  v (P ^ Q) by vI on 2
(3) P -> (P v (P ^ Q)) by proof 1-2
```

Side 2:

```
(1) | P v (P ^ Q) as assumption
(2) | (P v P) & (P v Q) distribution on 1
(3) | P v P &E on 2
(4) | P by simplification of 3
(5) (P v (P ^ Q)) -> P by proof 1-4
```

and you should be able to do the rest.

Comment: this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make a truth-table for the two propositions and see that they always share the same truth-values at each row.

Comment: If you don't want to use a truth-table, then you'll have to specify the rules of inference or equivalence that you're permitted to use.  For instance, you might use distribution to obtain the equivalence with (P v P) ^ (P v Q) which by idempotence is equivalent to P ^ (P v Q).  This implies P, so you get that the left-hand expression implies the right.

In the other direction, the result is immediate by the fact that P implies P v phi where phi is any sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it in words?

If both P and Q are true then P is true.
A fortiori if either P is true or both P and Q are true then P is true.

Converse is even easier - if P is true then either P is true or any R (including both P and Q) is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shortish proof starting with an assumption that the proposition is false:

```
 1. |asm: ¬((P v (P ^ Q)) ≡ P)
 2. |∴ (P v (P ^ Q)) v P)                       {from 1}
 3. |∴ ¬((P v (P ^ Q)) ^ P)                     {from 1}
 4. ||asm: P                                    {break 2}
 5. ||∴ ¬(P v (P ^ Q))                          {from 3 and 4}
 6. ||∴ ¬P                                      {from 5}
 7. |∴ ¬P                                       {from 4; 4 contradicts 6}
 8. |∴ (P v (P ^ Q))                            {from 2 and 7}
 9. |∴ (P ^ Q)                                  {from 7 and 8}
10. |∴ P                                        {from 9}
11. ∴ ((P v (P ^ Q)) ≡ P)                       {from 1; 7 contradicts 10}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that uses four different rules: conjunction elimination (∧E), disjunction elimination (∨E), disjunction introduction (∨I) and biconditional introduction (↔I).  See *forall x: Calgary Remix* for a description of these rules.

[image]

Regarding the concern: *I am not sure how to get rid of proposition Q.*

Note that "Q" was not used to help the proof along. It appeared on line 3 as part of the second case to consider in the disjunction elimination of line 1, but as a conjunction with "P" it could be ignored since all we needed was "P".

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/